# Question about a power adapter amperage

Tags: power-supply, power

I have a single board computer that needs 5v/1500-2000mA. I have a power adapter that outputs 5v/3A. Is it safe to use this power adapter?

Comment: Accept the answer as correct then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  3 A is 3000 mA - more than the computer needs, so the supply will not be overloaded.

The computer will only draw the current it requires.

Comment: Great, thank you.